# Merge navigation bar with Title and subtitle

Tags: beamer, navigation

The top of my slides have a title and subtitle (I eliminated the headline). However, I want to put the navigation bar, only for sections, at the corner right of the title and subtitle lines. This is shown below for the first slide. However, it is messy, as it changes the size of the bar and the font type and sizes are not consistent.

1. How can I adjust this properly so it retains the size of the bar of slide 2?
2. Is there a way I can create this for all slides? So far I do it by writing it on each slide's title, as can be seen below.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}
{ %
\fontsize{20}{25}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Topic 1 \hfill \insertsectionnavigation{2cm}}
\framesubtitle{Frame 1}
Frame 1
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Topic 2}
\framesubtitle{Frame 2}
Frame 2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't know how to show slide here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this redefining the `frametitle` template as defined by the `shadow` outer theme (internally used by `Warsaw`) to include the navigation bar. The theme displays the title and the subtitle using a `minipage` having a width of `\paperwidth` width, so I changed the width to `0.5\paperwidth` and added another `minipage` of the same width to add the navigation bar; of course, feel free to make the modifications that better suit your needs:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}
{ %
\fontsize{20}{25}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{myshadow theme}
{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \insertframetitle%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \strut\par%
          \else
            \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}%
          \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\paperwidth}
            \hfill\raisebox{0.5\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
              \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{\hskip1em}{\hskip1em}%
              }%
          \end{minipage}%
          }%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
    \vskip-0.2pt
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \vskip-2pt
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Topic 1}
\framesubtitle{Frame 1}
Frame 1
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Topic 2}
\framesubtitle{Frame 2}
Frame 2
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}{Topic 3}
\framesubtitle{Frame 3}
Frame 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting document:

[image]

Comment: I can't really understand the code but two things: I want it vertically aligned, so I replaced your horizontal navigation by \insertsectionnavigation by dissapears. I fail to see how to fix it. Also, how can I control the text size?

Comment: Got it! added \tiny in front of that command and changed some of the height properties. Now it works!! :)

Comment: I'm only missing some bits. There are more items than those that fit in the navigation bar, which doesn't adjust automatically. In fact, it changes according to title and subtitle. How can make them all visible?